# remove with javascript similar text join with other text

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove similar text in textarea with JavaScript

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="data" name="data">
this is the first similar apple and banana 
this is the second  apple and banana 
this is the third similar banana 
this is the first similar apple
</textarea>
```

what i aspect

```
    this is the second  apple and banana
```

so every thing has `similar` will be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following splits the text into an array of strings delimited by the newline character, filters out all the lines containing ‘similar’, and then rejoins the remaining lines.

`document.getElementById('data').value.split('\n').filter((item) => item.indexOf('similar')<0).join('\n')`

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding explanation of how and why the code works.

Comment: Thank you @JasonAller, next time I will add the description

Comment: Why wait for  next time? You can also do it now by [edit]ing your post and maybe attract some up-votes

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
document.getElementById("data").value.split("\n").filter(
  function(t) {
    return t.indexOf("similar") === -1;
  }
).join("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the string out of the text area using `document.getElementById("data")` and store it in a variable, lets call that variable `str`.

We can split the string into lines and filter out the lines that contain 'similar':
`str.split("\n").filter(line => !line.contains("similar"))`

And then you can then join the remaining lines back together and write it to the element.